# How did Rutherford conclude that most of the mass (as well as the positive charge) was concentrated in the nucleus?

Tags: experimental-physics, mass, nuclear-physics, scattering, atoms

Geiger and Marsden's experiment led Rutherford to believe that the positive charge and most of the mass of the atom was concentrated in a small region. I understand what led him to conclude the way the positive charge is positioned in the atom. But how did he conclude that most of the mass was in a small region (the nucleus)?

How did the distribution of the mass matter after all? Given that the electric force is greater than the gravitational force by many magnitudes, the force between the positice charge and the electrons was predominantly electric.

So how did Rutherford conclude that most of the mass is in the nucleus?

Comment: Rutherford assumed that the target nucleus did not recoil when the alpha particle interacted with it.

Comment: @Farcher Merely an assumption?

Comment: There is an effect. http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/scattering2.htm

Comment: See the Rutherford gold foil alpha particle scattering experiment. I shall not answer as @Manish Sahu has given a good explanation already.

Comment: @Farcher Using a fixed center assumption to build the comparison cross-section doesn't mean he assumed the mass in a vacuum. If you assume that the alpha interacts elastically with only one atom., then scattering angle much larger than 90 degrees force the mass ratio on you. This is one of many powerful results from the classical theory of scattering that relies only on the conservation of energy and momentum (a subject that tend to get short shrift in the pressure of a modern curriculum, but they were well known).

Comment: @dmckee I understand about the fact that one mass must be much greater than the other but since the angular distribution is not a function of the mass ratio can one directly find an order of magnitude (or better) value for the ratio of the masses from the scattering experiment?

Comment: I'll post a comment to clarify what my doubt is. Thompson's model proposed that the _mass_ **and** the _positive charge_ was uniformly distributed in the atom. With the electrons being raisins in a plum pudding of sorts. Also, when Rutherford performed his experiment it was known that the alpha particles had energy to pass through such uniform distribution of _mass_ **and** _positive charge_. My doubt basically revolves around the fact that the electric force is the key in the interaction between the alpha particles and the 'nucleus' (suggested by Rutherford).

Comment: Since the alpha particles rebounded in many of the cases it is certain that most of the positive charge was concentrated in a small volume. What puzzles me is how was it ascertained that that same region which contained the positive charge was also the one which carried most of the mass of the atom. Couldn't the mass have been thought to be distributed uniformly through the atom? Surely the mass isn't as significant is it? There is no actual collision taking place? The alpha particles comes as close as it can without actual touching the 'nucleus'.

Comment: Thompson said _mass_ **and** _positive_ charge are uniformly spread. Surely the alpha particles had energy to overcome a uniform mass distribution if not the positive charge (because the positive charge was in a small region). I'm just being stupid here but couldn't anyone have been lead to believe that the mass is uniformly distributed through the atom, just that the positive charge is centered in something called the _nucleus_. Apologies for all the stupidity.

Comment: @Farcher The angular distribution in the center of mass frame is not a function of the mass, ratio, but in the lab frame it certainly is. In particular the largest possible lab-frame scattering angle is $\psi_{max} = \arcsin (m_2/m_1)$ (see, eg line 389 of http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node52.html) which shows any backward scattering implies the target is heavier than the incident particle. Getting the mass ratio from the data is harder and requires a lot of statistics. But Rutherford was on reasonably solid ground assuming everything not an electron was in the nucleus.

Comment: @KunalPawar *"Surely the mass isn't as significant is it?"* Momentum must be conserved. Every change in velocity of the incident particle is reflected in a opposite sense change in velocity of the target, but the ratio of the size of those changes depends wholly on their relative masses.

Comment: @dmckee Agreed. Momentum must be conserved. I reiterate: couldn't it have been thought the mass is uniform throughout the atom while the charge is confined to something called the _nucleus_?

Comment: @Kunal Let's take that seriously for a moment. You are proposing that (a) the charge is nailed down to the heavy mass (it *must* be or the scattering would not have the observed character), but (b) it occupies only part of the volume of that mass and (c) the mass sticking out away from the charge doesn't affect any part of the scattering process. In other words that the scattering is as if the mass and charge coincide, but they fail to do so in some unmeasureable way. Occam's razor/the principle of parsimony tells us to leave that assumption aside until there is some reason to make it.

Comment: @dmckee So it's exactly what I thought I was doing– being stupid -.- Basically my assumption has no grounds because there are no observations which call for such an assumption.

Comment: Certainly, the gravitational force is  irrelevant, but inertia / momentum is not.

Answer (score 41):

This is a good example of how Science works.

Geiger and Marsden observed that some of the alpha particles were being backscattered. This is inconceivable if the alpha particle is scattered by a lighter particle.

If one considers a particle of mass $m$ and initial velocity $v_1$ striking a target of mass $m'$ at rest, without changing its direction, then its final velocity $v_2$ can assume two possible values,
$$v_2=v_1,\quad\mathrm{or}\quad v_2=-v_1\left(\frac{m'-m}{m'+m}\right).$$
The second solution gives that backscattering is only possible if the target has greater mass than the incident particle. By the time, the mass of the electron was known to be much smaller than the mass of the alpha particle so a backscattering event would imply that the scattering centers were in fact heavy positive nuclei. And indeed those scatterings were observed.

To formally check this, Rutherford obtained a formula for the number of scattered particles as a function of the scattering angle using the hypothesis of heavy nuclei (which is justified by the above paragraph). Geiger and Marsden did the experiment and the data agreed with Rutherford formula.

Comment: This. Classical scattering theory forces you to understand the nucleus as considerably heavier than the alpha.

Comment: There is no actual collision taking place is there? The alpha particle never actually touched the nucleus. It just came as close as its energy permitted and turned around (if it were destined for a head-on collision) or just scattered.

Comment: @KunalPawar  A collision or crash is an event in which two or more bodies exert forces on each other for a relatively short time. Although the most common colloquial use of the word "collision" refers to incidents in which two or more objects collide, the scientific use of the word "collision" implies nothing about the magnitude of the force.

Comment: @KunalPawar:  No electrons or nuclei make contact with each other when two billiard balls collide, either.  The forces involved in both cases are the same.

Comment: How did you derive $v_2=-v_1\frac{m'-m}{m'+m}$ ?

Comment: @Krish I just used momentum conservation.

Answer (score 38):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93Marsden_experiment) explains this rather well but I'll pick out the relevant stuff for you.

Before the Geiger–Marsden experiment, the general idea was that atoms were built of some permeable positive substrate in which some negative particles were floating around; the so called *plum-pudding* model.

If we shoot $\alpha$ particles on this setup they should all pass through the atoms since the positive substrate is thought to be permeable! (left side of the figure)

But when people did the experiment they saw that most particles went through while some scattered $180^\circ$ backwards, some even bent a small angle! (right side of the figure)

[image: Experiment]

The plum-pudding model had no problem with the particles that went through undisturbed but what about the ones that were backscattered? People theorized that there must be some solid core in the atom against which the $\alpha$ particles could scatter. The core couldn't be too big since only a small fraction of the $\alpha$ particles backscattered.

This leads to a model in which most of the mass (to which $\alpha$ particles can scatter) are in the center of the atom with the negative charges around it!

Answer (score 8):

Rutherford performed a series of experiments where he measured back scattering of $\alpha$ particles a function of thickness of metal foil. In the third part of the experiment he observed that around 1 in 8000 $\alpha$ particles were able to back scatter. This was possible only if it encountered large Electric field. Such large electric field can't be created by distributed charge,  but has to be created by some concentrated charge.  So this explains the concept of nucleus.

And since nucleus has most of the charge (protons are heavier than electron) it has most of the mass of the atom.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as posed. At the time when Rutherford postulated his model, the proton was unknown, let alone its mass.

Comment: @ Emilio Pisanty I agree that proton was not discovered until 1920 and Rutherford model actually supports the fact that nucleus could have carried +ve as well as -ve charge. But since $\alpha$ particles were deflected, nucleus had to be +ve charge.

It was also observed that scattering angle where maximum $\alpha$ particles were detected was directly proportional to the atomic mass of metal foil. This supports the fact that indeed nucleus had most of the mass. If mass was not a factor then, scattering angle would not be a function of atomic mass where we detect maximum $\alpha$ particles.

Comment: That $\alpha$ particles being deflected isn't the reason for concluding the nucleus is positive. IIRC, the scattering pattern is not that sensitive to the charge of the targets. Positivity of the nucleus follows from matter being electrically neutral and electrons being negative.