# Rutherford experiment of alpha particles

Tags: nuclear-physics

What are the effect of electrons on alpha particles during this experiment? 
Also why do we neglect them ?

Comment: Possibly related to [How did Rutherford conclude that most of the mass (as well as the positive charge) was concentrated in the nucleus?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326320/how-did-rutherford-conclude-that-most-of-the-mass-as-well-as-the-positive-charg/326371#326371)

Comment: We neglect them because they have a trivial effect on scattering. Part is the reduced mass issue noted in one answer. Next is that the scattering happens at distances much smaller than the electron cloud. Then, there is the experimental fact that scattering with a +1 charged alpha is no different from scattering with a +2 ion.

Comment: @JonCuster Zero , etc. Does the previous question really address this OP's question regarding *specifically* the electron? I read it and it really doesn't appear to at least in terms of momentum, apart from charge. Size matters, but no mention of relative size in previous answer.

Comment: @docscience - it isn't clear to me how the OP thinks the electron might impact the scattering. That makes it hard to figure out what the OP is looking for. Bottom line, though, is that an electron or two will not change the scattering event at all.

Answer (score 3):

The ratio between the mass of an electron and the mass of an alpha particle is on the order of 1/7300. And the ratio of the mass between a gold atom's nucleus and an alpha particle is about 200/1. So even though the speed of the electron might be faster than the speed of the gold nucleus it doesn't make up for the huge difference in mass and thus momentum.

Therefore between the two collisions, the alpha particle will 'bounce' back when colliding with a gold nucleus, but not with an electron.